# Perl losing/resetting CGI parameters between forms

Tags: html, forms, perl, cgi

I'm having an interesting problem.

I've written a Perl script that calls a few subroutines that display HTML. The subroutines also contain form tags.

I currently have three input `type="submit"` buttons and I've got them all set to `name="submitbtn"`.  I'm distinguishing between them by saying

```
if ($cgi->param('submitbtn') eq 'value')
```

I call my first subroutine, HTML is displayed, the user enters information and presses `Save` (a submit button).

Another subroutine is called and HTML is displayed. I allow the user to press `Return` (a submit button that calls a subroutine and goes to another HTML page) or `Continue` (a submit button that calls another subroutine to commit everything to the database).

When I press either submit button, my CGI parameters are "reset" I guess. I can't seem to figure out how to pass my original parameters.

I say

```
my $cgi = CGI->new;
my %form = $cgi->Vars;
```

I've tried

```
sub(%form);
```

and things of this nature but no dice. I'm pretty new to Perl. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Every time the user submits a form, the server script starts fresh, with no memory from the previous time. You need to use cookies or hidden form elements to preserve information from one run to the next.

Comment: If you have a *lot* of data then put it in a database keyed by a session ID. Store the session ID as a cookie so that you can get your data back when a new request comes in.

Comment: Putting only the session ID in the cookie and keeping everything else in a database (or other server-side storage) is also a Very Good Idea if any of the information is potentially sensitive, since the cookie gets passed from the client to the server and back with every request and it can potentially be intercepted on each trip.